# Error: Member "assertNotEqual" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256

Tags: solidity, solc

I am trying to run test cases in `sol-unit` for Solidity, but when I compile my code with `solc` compiler I get an error. I don't think the error is critical, but there is very little material on net about it:

> demotest.sol:13:9: Error: Member "assertNotEqual" not found or not visible 
> after argument-dependent lookup in uint256 
> demo.getX().assertNotEqual(TEST_VAL, "Values are not equal");

```
contract Demo {

    uint _x = 0;

    function setX(uint x){
        _x = x;
    }

    function getX() constant returns (uint x){
        return _x;
    }
}
```

```
import "./Demo.sol";

contract DemoTest is Demo {

    uint constant TEST_VAL = 55;

    // Test method starts with 'test' and will thus be recognized (2).
    function testSetX(){
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.setX(TEST_VAL);

        // Assert methods bound to type. Assertions will automatically fire off a test event (3).
        demo.getX().assertNotEqual(TEST_VAL, "Values are not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not a deprecated library?

Answer (score 1):

`getX()` returns a `uint` which does not have a member called `assertNotEqual`. You are probably missing a library that contains that function and the statement that adds the library to all uint types: `using LibraryName for uint`.

Answer (score 1):

I use Assert.sol as:

Assert.notEqual(Value, ComparativeValue, Message) and it works at leats for equal and notEqual methods